# Oracle: SELECT to_number('3+11+7') FROM dual; gives ora-01722

Tags: oracle11g

I am using oracle 11g R2. When i query SELECT to_number('3+11+7') FROM dual. It gives ora-01722.
and when i remove single quotes, SELECT to_number(3+11+7) FROM dual. Then it gives answer 21.
I just removed single quotes from string. How can i do it with built in functions.
Thanks.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do - evaluate any mathematical expression that you receive as a string? Where does the original value come from and how is it passed to you?

Answer (score 2):

You could pass evaluation of the expression to XML:

```
select to_number(xmlquery('3+11+7' returning content)) from dual;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=109fb9d0d30084b9abc9668bc7dfcd7f)

Comment: Alex Pool - How can we do it in oracle forms 6i and 11g

Comment: Where *exactly* in Forms? Trigger (which one?)? Procedure? Elsewhere? Screenshot might help.

Comment: @Abdullah - this query works in 11g (see the db<>fiddle). Your question doesn't mention Forms so I don't know what else you might need to do beyond this.

Comment: @Alex Poole i have post new question the link is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71147382/oracle-forms-6i-assign-a-text-field-t-3117-to-a-number-field-n-n-to