# Oracle Forms 6i : assign a text field T ('3+11+7') to a number field N (:N := to_number(:T);) gives error ora-01722

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I am using Forms 6i with oracle 11g R2. I have a text field T that have value = '3+11+7'. I want sum of text field. when i assign T to a number field N **(:N := to_number(:T))**. It gives ora-01722. I want total of text field that is 21 to the next field that is number field. plz suggest, how can i do this.
Thanks

This is the illustration :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Forms isn't particularly good at executing some commands; its PL/SQL engine is *oldfashioned*, but - it can call a **stored function** which runs in the database.

```
SQL> create or replace function f_result (par_value in varchar2)
  2    return number
  3  is
  4    retval number;
  5  begin
  6    select to_number(xmlquery(par_value returning content))
  7      into retval
  8      from dual;
  9
 10    return retval;
 11  end;
 12  /

Function created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> select f_result('3+11-2') result from dual;

    RESULT
----------
        12

SQL>
```

---

In Forms, I created a simple control block with two fields: one accepts numeric operations you want, another one displays the result. How? By executing the `WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM` trigger on the 1st field. Its code is as simple as

```
:result := f_result(:values);
```

[image]